# integer input only do while loop, stuck infinite looping

Tags: java

I've been playing with this code for an hour now trying to make it only accept integers. Atm when you input a character the loop is infinite, i can't seem to progress from here.

```
do
{   
    System.out.println("Enter student's number: "); 
}
while (!in.hasNextInt());
number = in.nextInt();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Place the `nextInt` call inside the loop..

Comment: I've done this and it now crashes when i enter a character instead of a number

Comment: @user3050340 Then there's a descriptive error message.

Answer (score 1):

while (!in.hasNextInt());

Here, `in.hasNextInt()` gives you a `true` when `in` has next element in its stream as an `int`. 
If it is not `int`, it will return `false`.

`!false = true`, which projects :

```
while(true);
```

this leads to the infinite loop.

Hope you understood.